# DESede-ECB Encryption-Decryption

Tags: java, encryption, des, tripledes

I'm trying to Encrypt and decrypt a string in java using the following code:

```
public byte[] encrypt(String message) throws Exception {
    final MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("md5");
    final byte[] digestOfPassword = md.digest("MYKEY12345"
            .getBytes("utf-8"));
    final byte[] keyBytes = Arrays.copyOf(digestOfPassword, 24);
    for (int j = 0, k = 16; j < 8;) {
        keyBytes[k++] = keyBytes[j++];
    }

    final SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "DESede");
//        final IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(new byte[8]);
    final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);

    final byte[] plainTextBytes = message.getBytes("utf-8");
    final byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal(plainTextBytes);
    // final String encodedCipherText = new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder()
    // .encode(cipherText);



    Log.d("base64", Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipherText));

    return cipherText;
}


public String decrypt(byte[] message) throws Exception {
    final MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("md5");
    final byte[] digestOfPassword = md.digest("MYKEY12345"
            .getBytes("utf-8"));
    final byte[] keyBytes = Arrays.copyOf(digestOfPassword, 24);
    for (int j = 0, k = 16; j < 8;) {
        keyBytes[k++] = keyBytes[j++];
    }

    final SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "DESede");
//    final IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(new byte[8]);
    final Cipher decipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
    decipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);

    // final byte[] encData = new
    // sun.misc.BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(message);
    final byte[] plainText = decipher.doFinal(message);

    return new String(plainText, "UTF-8");
}
```

usage:

```
byte[] codedtext = new Common().encrypt("HELLOWORLD!"); // Function to get the Encrption
```

Output:

```
 base64: Ya9zBTukyOmdOh5/5vCaGA== // encrypted string converted to base64
 Encrypted : [B@d41c149
```

ToDecrypt:

```
 String decodedtext = new Common().decrypt(codedtext); // To decrypt String
```

Output:

```
Decrypted : HELLOWORLD!  // from Encrypted string
```

Now if i use the same Key and String to get the encryption key online i get different values.

[Using this link](https://encode-decode.com/des-ecb-encrypt-online/) to verify my encryption/decryption.

I'm just starting in encryption/decryption so any help is appreciated about any thing that i'm doing wrong here.

Comment: And i'm recieveing different values every time when i encrypt/decrypt the same string with same key.

Comment: Is the question why the ciphertexts differ? There are several possible reasons for this: The website will hardly implement your key derivation via MD5, possibly you have additionally selected the wrong algorithm and/or mode, possibly the website uses a different padding or possibly it's simply buggy (which is not uncommon for crypto websites). Note that your code is insecure in several ways: broken MD5, key derivation via digest, hard coded password, ECB mode. Also, TDES is slow. Btw, a changing ciphertext indicates a mode with an IV.

Comment: This `Encrypted : [B@d41c149` shows that you are trying to print out a byte array by calling the `.toString()` method on that array, explicitly or implicitly due to String conversion. This doesn't do what you think it does. To print out binary/arbitrary byte sequences you should first either hex-encode them or base64 encode them, which you've already done.

Comment: The link you have points to single DES in ECB mode, not DESede.

Answer (score 0):

You need

```
final byte[] plainText = decipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(message));
```

Comment: No he doesn't. OP's code _prints_ base64 to System.out, but stores the raw (nonbase64) value in codedtext.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 the reason i said that is that it *seemed* he was feeding back the output of the encryption code into the decryption code (a natural thing to do). Natural too for the Base64 in the decryption to mirror that of the encryption routine